# Aerosoleans - How much do they eat?

Tags: creature-design, science-fiction, far-future

Aerosolians or 'loopies' live on hypersonic trains. They stick to the sheetmetal and collected microbes from aerosols captured by tiny pockets in their skin. Because of the high speed they can collect enough energy through only bacteria, yeasts and protozans.

They are about the size of an adult beaver. They hardly ever move and the trains are moving at about 7000km/h for 8 hours a day.

**How much do they eat?**

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: I recognize the train from Heinlein's Starman Jones!  Is this your own work?  Did you invent these?  I see your username is the same as the sketches.  I hope yes!  I hope yes!!!  How cool!  Welcome to WBStack!

Comment: And someone hung a swing on the train loop!!  SWEEEET

Comment: Yes these are mine :) nice that you noticed the swing detail. I'd like to see a future where hyper advanced tech is closely entangled with nature. As you see here quite literally.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. It would help if you put the details of these creatures also in the text of the question. Also, we prefer 1 focused question per post. You can find our standards and guidance in the [help]

Comment: @L.Dutch Thank you! I changed some details.

Comment: 300 km/h doesn't sound really hypersonic

Comment: Indeed! You're rightly debunking my details. I changed it to 7000 km/h.

Answer (score 1):

Since blue whales are very large ann only eat Krill I think that your creatures could eat relatively small amount of bacteria( and bacteria are abundant) to live.

Answer (score 1):

From your description of the creatures it looks like their method of consumption is passive. Since you said they hardly ever move implies they can  move if they wished. So they are a higher on the evolutionary tree than sea sponges. A sloth consumes around 110 calories /day. About as much as a big apple.
or:
1 Cup of Blueberries
1 Hard-Boiled Egg.
1 Orange.
1 Cup of Strawberries
1 Piece of String Cheese
8 Baby Carrots
1 Cup of Cheerios
1 to 2 Cups of Fresh Melon  .

Not knowing how they deal with their environment. Assume it can get cold and hot, changing air pressures that's about as close as I can imagine to get.

Answer (score 1):

We need a creature that subsists on microscopic organisms, with an aerodynamic shape, and a land dweller.  **I propose a slime mold.**

[image: slime mold]

https://www.sciencealert.com/this-creeping-slime-is-changing-how-we-think-about-intelligence

These macroscopic amoeboid sheets adopt aerodynamic shapes by flowing according to forces produced by air currents.  Shapes of each organism on the train will differ according to the topography of the train and local air flow.  Problems solving of this type is within the power of slime molds; see link.

As depicted in the drawing in the OP, these creatures tend to have a rear portion lifted above the level of the train.  The consequent low pressure under the organisms entrains dust and microbes that are its food.

Inorganic particles and waste are pushed thru the plasmodium body to the top, where it accumulates and serves as a sort of carapace to protect from UV light and also minimize water losses.  Unfortunately that makes these organisms look like patches of dirt on the train.

I was worried that living on the train would dessicate these organisms.  But it turns out the trains are so fast that the high speed / low pressure air produces a vapor trail or "bullet trace" like that of an actual bullet.  The lower pressure air by the trais has less ability to hold moisture which precipitates out in droplets.  It is always humid right next to the train.

But as regards the OP and "how much they eat" - it depends!  The aerosoleans come in very different sizes.  Occasionally a big one will occupy the whole top of the train, side to side.   Metabolic rates will vary with temperature.  And "eat" - does that mean caloric intake, intake by volume or intake by mass?  The aerosoleans wind up taking in a lot of dust that they cannot use as food.

---

I am sad to say I could not find any real life examples of any of the polyphyletic group called "slime molds" actually using a carapace to protect against dessication, so I made that up.  As regards bullet trains leaving a vapor trace the physics is sound but I could not find images of a bullet train leaving such a trail.

Comment: Woohoo what a great addition to my sketch. The slime shape adjusting to the particular conditions of the train is a nice one. And indeed desiccation is a good point. Thanks!